# How to find out the length of an array without .length

Tags: java, arrays

i have to find out how long a char array is. 
I can´t use the .length because it isn´t allowed.
CAn you please help me???
Error: The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) char, null

I have it like this...

```
  public void len(){
        int i=0;
        while(i>0){
            if (Array[i] != null) {
                System.out.println("not null");

            }
            else{
                System.out.println(i);
            }           
    }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by .lenght isn't allowed?

Comment: Homeworks... as always

Comment: he probably has this for homework, and his lecturer probably specified that you cant use .length

Comment: That's how you find the length. We're not really here to teach you how to intentionally do things the wrong way. Use `.length`

Comment: You could check for an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` but `.lenght` is the right way to do it.

Comment: @nhouser9 Or... it's likely a school assignment just for practice.

Comment: I'd probably be that wise-ass student who builds an off-site API which accepts a string and returns its length, and then in this code would integrate with that API.  The client-side Java code would have successfully not used `.length`.

Comment: Yes it is a question for homework. And i don´t know how to find out without .length.

Comment: Are you sure the homework isn't asking for the length of like an object array? like a LinkedList or ArrayList?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't even make sense not to allow the use of `.length` field to access the length of the array. I think you must have misunderstood something.

Anyway, here's a "dirty" way to get the length:

```
public static <T> int lengthOfArray(T[] array) {
    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {
            T t = array[count];
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return count;
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

Note that you need to use `Character[]` instead of a `char[]`.

Please DO NOT use this in production code!

Answer (score 1):

This is just another way to do it, it's a little trick that uses the `List` interface and then get the data from there, I don't know if it's allowed and for sure is not the best way.

```
public static <T> int len(T[] array) {
    return Arrays.asList(array).size();
}
```

Remember that you can't pass primitive types arrays to this function.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, your program does actually nothing since i is never superior to 0, here you go, thats the simplest way to do it:

```
public void len(){
    end = false;
    for(int i = 0; !end; i++){
        try{
            char c = Array [i];
            System.out.println("not null : " + i);
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException){
            System.out.println("End of the array");
            end = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int length = java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a non-existent array element doesn't evaluate to null, it throws an exception, so you can't compare it with null. Here's a solution that finds the length by testing for the exception and minimizes the number of tests using a binary search:

```
static int getArrayLengthStupidWay(Object array) {
    int low = 0, high = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while (low != high) {
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        try {
            java.lang.reflect.Array.get(array, mid);
            low = mid + 1;
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            high = mid;
        }
    }
    return low;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What is a chain of chars?

```
int lenght = new String(charArray).size();
```

Comment: Thats not an answer

Comment: why not? Please explain.

Comment: Avoid asking a question in an answer, and OP clearly wants not to use size/length functions, thats why he's using an array of char. And this question already has a pretty good answer

Comment: The question was rhetorical, and the OP wanted to avoid `.length` only...

Comment: "i have to find out how long a char array is" I think its clear

Comment: communication is never sharp and leaves room for interpretations. Your is different than mine and I'm not going to participate in the flame war you tryinig to start here...